# How to place div below canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have some HTML5 code containing canvas and I can't put a div below the canvas, here is part of the code:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
   <div id="animation_container" style="position: absolute; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00); width:2000px; height:1520px; z-index: 3">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="1520" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);"></canvas>
   </div>
</div>
<div style= " z-index: 3">
   <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to remove the style="position: relative;" on the first div.